# iOS Gamecenter Programmatic Matchmaking

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I'm trying to implement a real-time multiplayer game with a custom UI (no `GKMatchMakerViewController`). I'm using `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:
^(NSString *playerID, BOOL reachable)` to find a local player, and then initiating a match request with the `GKMatchmaker` singleton (which I have already initiated).

Here's where I'm having trouble. When I send a request, the completion handler fires almost immediately, without an error, and the match it returns has an expected player count of zero. Meanwhile, the other player definitely has not responded to the request.

Relevant code:

```
- (void) findMatch
{
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = NUM_PLAYERS_PER_MATCH; //2
request.maxPlayers = NUM_PLAYERS_PER_MATCH; //2
if (nil != self.playersToInvite)
{
    // we always successfully get in this if-statement
    request.playersToInvite = self.playersToInvite;
    request.inviteeResponseHandler = ^(NSString *playerID, GKInviteeResponse
                                       response)
    {
        [self.delegate updateUIForPlayer: playerID accepted: (response ==
                                                              GKInviteeResponseAccepted)];
    };
}
request.inviteMessage = @"Let's Play!";

[self.matchmaker findMatchForRequest:request
    withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Print the error
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else if (match != nil)
        {
            self.currentMatch = match;
            self.currentMatch.delegate = self;

            // All players are connected
            if (match.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
            {
                // start match
                [self startMatch];
            }
            [self stopLookingForPlayers];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!  I needed to call `- (void)matchForInvite:(GKInvite *)invite completionHandler:(void (^)(GKMatch *match, NSError *error))completionHandler` in my invitation handler so that both players have the same match data.